# Приложение на python, css, html для OC, Linux, iOS

Tags: python, html, css

Пишу приложение по поиску рецептов исходя из ингредиентов и мне нужен рабочий поисковик. То есть сайт - https://eda.ru - не могу найти API этого сайта и поисковика, чтобы с ним работать. Возможно как то добавить (тавтология) поисковик сайта в поисковик своего приложения с выводом в моем же приложении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: P.S. Это мой первый проект для git'a. Хотелось бы разработать какое то уникальное приложение, хоть и без своей базы данных.

Comment: Даже не найдется человека, который знает и может мне что-то подсказать?